# Samples, isosamples, and how they affect contour lines

Tags: gnuplot, contour

Contour lines generated by gnuplot can look pretty strange (unexpected) if you do not set both `samples` and `isosamples` to appropriate values. I struggled for hours to find out how exactly `set samples` and `set isosamples` affect the appearance of contour lines, however, all I observed is that setting both to sufficiently large values will generate good-looking contours. Still, I want to understand how exactly this works.

1. What is the difference between `set samples` and `set isosamples` in the context of contour lines?
2. How does `set samples` affect the generation of contour lines?
3. How does `set isosamples` affect the generation of contour lines?

For example, consider the following simple case:

```
unset surface
set contour
set cntrparam levels discrete 10, 20
set samples 250, 2
set isosamples 2, 250
set view map
splot x**2 + y**2
```

To generate correct contour lines, it appears you need to set the first parameter of `samples` and the second parameter of `isosamples` to sufficiently large values. However, setting the second parameter of `samples` and the first parameter of `isosamples` to the smallest possible value does no harm. This is not exactly intuitive. So how does this work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, a discussion on what `samples` and `isosamples` where designed to do. This is best when viewing the actual plot and not the contour map.

`samples` is used to set the number of function evaluations along an axis in the range being plotted. For `splot` (3-D images), you can control samples in both independent directions x and y. Here is a sample where the x-direction only has 4 evaluations and the y-direction has 200:

```
reset
set xrange [-10:10]
set yrange [-10:10]
set xlabel 'X'
set ylabel 'Y'
set samples 4,200
splot x**2+y**2
```

In the following 2 images note that along the x-direction, the function is only evaluated 4 times and straight lines are drawn between them. Along the y-direction, it is evaluated 200 times and it looks like 'smooth' curves. Note that in both directions, exactly 10 lines are drawn. I will get to that below while discussing isolines.

Looking toward x-axis:
[image: 4 Samples along x-direction]

Looking toward y-axis:
[image: 200 Samples along y-direction]

---

So, 10 lines in each axis direction are drawn because the default value for isolines in both x and y directions is 10. We can change this at will. Lets increase samples in both directions for a nice smooth curves but demonstrate isosamples.

```
reset
set xrange [-10:10]
set yrange [-10:10]
set xlabel 'X'
set ylabel 'Y'
set samples 200,200
set isosamples 4,12
splot x**2+y**2
```

Note the nice smooth curves in both directions. Along the x-axis, there are only 4 points where, along the y-axis, the surface curves are drawn and along the y-axis, there are 12 points where surface curves are drawn parallel to the x-axis.

[image: isosamples example]

---

The above examples demonstrate the primary purpose of `set samples` and `set isosamples`. They only indirectly affect contours. In your case, you are only interested in the contour map without even displaying the surface plot. A clue as to how gnuplot plots contours is in its explanation of how contours can be drawn with discreet data.

Gromacs:

> In order to draw contours, the data should be organized as "grid data".  In
>    such a file all the points for a single y-isoline are listed, then all the
>    points for the next y-isoline, and so on.  A single blank line (a line
>    containing no characters other than blank spaces and a carriage return and/or
>    a line feed) separates one y-isoline from the next.

From this explanation, gnuplot seems to prefer to pick an x value and draw a y-isoline. We can deduce then that when gnuplot draws contours from functions, that it picks x values and draws y-isolines. Therefore having many x samples and many y isolines draws hi resolution contours while the y samples and the x isolines are irrelevant (if you are not drawing the surface).

Comment: A y-isoline is a line connecting points having equal y-coordinates (and thus varying x-coordinates). What exactly do you mean by picking an x-value and drawing a y-isoline?

Comment: Poorly worded. Picks x values to cycle through so you want x samples to be high but for each x, it draws contours by examining the y iso-lines so you want y isosamples to be high.