# Plotting a 3D surface with Gnuplot (splot + hidden3d) destroys edge

Tags: gnuplot, surface

I work in aerodynamic stability analysis and I want to create a general script to plot my eigenvectors. I am plotting a 3D surface and my data is an ordered multi-domain grid. I store my data in a dat file in the format stated in the Gnuplot book. So far I haven't had problems, but my plot after applying "set hidden3d" looses spots on the edge of my plotted surface.

Used script:

```
set term aqua
# Axis Ranges
# -------------
#set xrange []
set yrange [0:10]
#set zrange []

set hidden3d offset 0 # surface transparence(not see through) - offset 0 -> no color difference between upper and lower surface
set contour
set cntrparam level 10 # Number of contour levels
set cntrlabel onecolor # Colormap of contours

set xtics font "Times-Roman, 22"
set ytics font "Times-Roman, 22"
set ztics font "Times-Roman, 22"

set xlabel "Z-Axis" offset -0.1,1 font "Times-Roman,22" rotate by 0 # offset <x,y>
set ylabel "Y-Axis" offset 0.1,1 font "Times-Roman,22" rotate by 0 # offset <x,y>
set zlabel "X-Axis" offset -0.1,1 font "Times-Roman,22" rotate by 90 # offset <x,y>

splot 'mode.csv' w l linetype -1 notitle
```

Plot without "hidden3d"

[image]

Plot with "hidden3d"

[image]

Comment: Without your data we can't easily reproduce your exact issue. Could you please provide your data or at least a minimal dataset to reproduce this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Based on visual comparison of those two images, I think that the relevant difference is not hidden/nohidden.  It appears that the setting for samples and/or isosamples has changed, and the finer sampling in the "without hidden3d" causes it to render an edge that is not sampled in the other plot.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you ought to set isosamples and/or samples in your script

"When a function surface plot is being done without the removal of hidden lines, set samples controls the number of points sampled along each isoline; see set samples (p. [*]) and set hidden3d (p. [*]). The contour algorithm assumes that a function sample occurs at each isoline intersection, so change in samples as well as isosamples may be desired when changing the resolution of a function surface/contour."

See https://gnuplot.sourceforge.net/docs_4.2/node191.html for details, as well as [Samples, isosamples, and how they affect contour lines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51237482/samples-isosamples-and-how-they-affect-contour-lines)

Comment: Thank you, I tried to play with the settings for both samples and iso-samples. I tried an overkill of: 1000by1000 for both samples and iso-samples. Yet I still see a missing spot on the edge of my surface when using hidden3d

Comment: Might be a bug then. Report it https://sourceforge.net/p/gnuplot/bugs/